# Disable one thermal sensor from laptop

Tags: temperature

Dell Latitude E5550 sometimes reboots without no reason. I made a script that run `sensors` once per second, and it contained lines like

```
Ambient:        +39.0°C  
Ambient:        +38.0°C  
Ambient:        +44.0°C  
Ambient:        +38.0°C  
Ambient:            N/A  
Ambient:       +127.0°C  
Ambient:       +127.0°C  
Ambient:        +38.0°C
```

so quite clearly one thermal sensor is failing. (CPU temp sensor seems to work.)

First, why `sensors` show for example

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan:    0 RPM
CPU:            +46.0°C  
Ambient:        +47.0°C  
SODIMM:         +34.0°C  
Other:          +30.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +52.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +51.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +52.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
temp2:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp3:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
```

i.e. what are all those temperatures? Second, can I disable shutdown from the ambient thermal sensor?

Comment: *quite clearly one thermal sensor is failing* which one? the "N/A" or the two "+127.0"?

Comment: It is the same sensor, "Ambient", that is giving both +127 and N/A. "CPU", "SODIMM" and "Other" seems to be OK.

Comment: oh, I see, that's several readings - I understand now